# R: conditionally replace values in loop

Tags: r, loops, replace, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like so:

```
rel      <- c(2, 5, NA, 3, 6)
year.in  <- c(4, NA, 2, 3, 2)
year.out <- c(6, 7, NA, 5, 4)
year.1   <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
year.2   <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
year.3   <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
year.4   <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
year.5   <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) 

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(rel, year.in, year.out, year.1, year.2, year.3, 
                      year.4, year.5))
```

What I would like to do is update the missing values in year.1 - year.5 with the value of 'rel', but only if: (year.in >= year.i AND year.out <= year.i) (with i is 1:5)

Focussing on the just the year of entry, I came up with this:

```
for (i in 1:5) ifelse(df$year.in < i,
    df[paste("year", i, sep= ".")]<- NA,
    df[paste("year", i, sep= ".")]<- df["rel"])
```

But this merely replaces all year.i variables with the value of rel.

I have two questions:

- how can I update the year.i variables with the 'rel' values on the conditions mentioned?
- is it bad to use the if else statement here?

Best and thanks in advance,

Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

for(i in 1:5) dt[year.in <= i & i <= year.out, paste0('year.', i) := rel]

dt
#   rel year.in year.out year.1 year.2 year.3 year.4 year.5
#1:   2       4        6     NA     NA     NA      2      2
#2:   5      NA        7     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
#3:  NA       2       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
#4:   3       3        5     NA     NA      3      3      3
#5:   6       2        4     NA      6      6      6     NA
```

Comment: Thanks, this is of great help. I'll make sure to study the data.table package more in depth!

Answer (score 1):

I'd `melt` your data using the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)    
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars=c('rel', 'year.in', 'year.out'))
```

Dig out the numeric year:

```
df.melt$year <- as.integer(gsub('year\\.', '', df.melt$variable))
```

Then use vectorized operations:

```
subsetter <- with(df.melt, year.in >= year & year.out <= year.out)
subsetter[is.na(subsetter)] <- FALSE
df.melt$value[subsetter] <- df.melt$rel[subsetter]
```

However, in your example, everything fails your condition.

Using `ifelse` is perfectly acceptable, however, don't do assignment inside.  Instead assign its result to something, like below.  The issue was that the two assignments you were performing inside the `ifelse` were not on each subset but instead acting as though they were just run independently.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  year_col <- paste('year', i, sep='.')
  df[[year_col]] <- ifelse(df$year.in >= i & df$year.out <= i,
                         df$rel,
                         df[[year_col]])
}
```

To answer your bullets:

- See above.
- There is nothing specifically wrong with using `ifelse` and sometimes it is handy to do so for readability.  However, it is a "looping" construct and thus can often be replaced by a more efficient vectorized solution.

Comment: Dear Justin, thank you for explicitly addressing my questions. I am sorry to say, that I have difficulty with running your code. The first piece of code works fine, but does not provide the expected output. e.g. a value of 2 in year 1, while year.in == 4 and year.out == 6. The for loop produces warnings in my case: Warning messages: "In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, year_col, value = list(c(NA_real_,  :
  provided 5 variables to replace 1 variables"

Comment: Thanks for the note, my mistake.  The unexpected output is because you have your condition written backwards in your question.  However, the warning was unintentional and is fixed by using `[[` to index the `df` by `year_col` (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. Yes I was inconsistent in the condition statement :[