# I am attempting to update a column row by row in a loop but the column keeps getting overwritten by the next loop through

Tags: r, dplyr, logic

```
install.packages("iterators")
library(iterators)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

ActiveAssets      <- c(0, 23, 56, 12, 69)
clusteNum         <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2)
dbname.servername <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dbname            <- c('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO')
Rank              <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
mean.value        <- c(123, 456, 789, 159, 357)
NewServer         <- c('0', '0', '0', '0', '0') 


df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ActiveAssets, clusteNum, dbname.servername,     
dbname, Rank, mean.value, NewServer))
servermeanAsset <-aggregate(df$ActiveAssets ~ df$dbname.servername,  df ,     
mean)

overallmean <- mean(servermeanAsset$`df$ActiveAssets`)

compare <- iter(df, by='row')

R <- {

  currentedit <- nextElem(compare)

  filtered <- filter(df, currentedit$dbname.servername !=     
df$dbname.servername & currentedit$ActiveAssets < df$ActiveAssets))

  ordered <- filtered[with(filtered, order(filtered$mean.value,     
filtered$ActiveAssets)),]

  slice <- slice(ordered, 1)

  df %>% mutate(NewServer = replace(slice$dbname.servername,     
currentedit$dbname == df$dbname & currentedit$Rank == df$Rank, 
slice$dbname.servername))

}

Which returns the output for the first run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0         1                 1             ABC    1    123         1
23         2                 2            DEF    2    456         <NA>
56         1                 3            GHI    3    789         <NA>
12         3                 4            JKL    4    159         <NA>
69         2                 5            MNO    5    357         <NA>

Which returns the output for the second run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0         1                 1             ABC    1    123         1
23         2                 2            DEF    2    456         <NA>
56         1                 3            GHI    3    789         1
12         3                 4            JKL    4    159         <NA>
69         2                 5            MNO    5    357         <NA>

What I want it to return in the first run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0          1                 1           ABC    1         123    2
23         2                 2           DEF    2         456    0
56         1                 3           GHI    3         789    0
12         3                 4           JKL    4         159    0
69         2                 5           MNO    5         357    0
What I want to return for the second run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0          1                 1           ABC    1         123    2
23         2                 2           DEF    2         456    3
56         1                 3           GHI    3         789    0
12         3                 4           JKL    4         159    0
69         2                 5           MNO    5         357    0

What I want to return for the third run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0          1                 1           ABC    1         123    2
23         2                 2           DEF    2         456    3
56         1                 3           GHI    3         789    5
12         3                 4           JKL    4         159    0
69         2                 5           MNO    5         357    0
What I want to return for the fourth run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0          1                 1           ABC    1         123    2
23         2                 2           DEF    2         456    3
56         1                 3           GHI    3         789    5
12         3                 4           JKL    4         159    1
69         2                 5           MNO    5         357    0
What I want to return for the fifth run:
ActiveAssets clusteNum dbname.servername dbname Rank mean.value NewServer
0          1                 1           ABC    1         123    2
23         2                 2           DEF    2         456    3
56         1                 3           GHI    3         789    5
12         3                 4           JKL    4         159    1
69         2                 5           MNO    5         357    0
-- the fifth run shouldn't move because there isn't another row with a 
different server value and and ActiveAsset value more than its value.
```

So what I am attempting to do is to look at the data I have on a one row basis (I will put this in a loop later on that will loop through until the newserver column has no '0' fields left in it) and row by row go through the data.  By row I want to grab the smallest database (determined by the active asset) that isn't in the same server as the selected row and then take the servername from that other row and write it to the newserver column in the currently selected row.

What I am finding is I can step through the dataset row by row and it filters/orders/slices the data just fine but when I try to write the servername of the slice to the newserver column of df it will overwrite what is in other rows of that column negating any return that was given in previous runs.

I have read through and tried recommendations from the following links for reference:
 [Look for cell within a data frame and replace its value without loops R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702622/look-for-cell-within-a-data-frame-and-replace-its-value-without-loops-r)

[R: conditionally replace values in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663515/r-conditionally-replace-values-in-loop)

[Populating a data frame in R in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442461/populating-a-data-frame-in-r-in-a-loop)

[For loop with if condition on multiple R functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417747/for-loop-with-if-condition-on-multiple-r-functions)

[R An if else statement inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486174/r-an-if-else-statement-inside-a-for-loop)

*What am I doing wrong?*

I need assistance finding out how to get that last row to write to the newserver column for one row only (the row in the currentedit) and not alter any other row in the newserver column.

Edit: Provided output of the code.

Comment: Where's the loop? I see no `for`, `while`, or `repeat` in your code.

Comment: Please provide an expected output table.

Comment: @r2evans I will be adding in the loop once I have the output doing what I want. I see no benefit to waiting for a loop to finish during the testing phase.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat I have gone through and added in what the code currently produces vs what I want it to produce. Honestly I can fiddle with the selection logic till the cows come home that isn't the issue in my real dataset, the issue is that I can't get that last line of the nested code to write to the table correctly.

Comment: Just trying to see if I understood your question. In the first run, we check row 1, we find ActiveAsset = 0, then what ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat  We find that the Active Asset = 0 Then we look through the rest of the rows and find a row with both a different server number and a higher Active Asset number than is in the current row. We then sort by both the mean value and active asset amounts in that filtered down sample from the step above. From that ordered group we select the top row and from that top row we take the server number and place that server number in the NewServer column but only in the row of our original row, in this case the row with Active Asset = 0

Comment: ´clusteNum´ is the server number ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat server number is dbname.servername on our system servernames are numbers so I use them interchangeably but that was confusing language and for that I am sorry. clusteNum is a different column that is used by logic elsewhere.

Comment: sorting is to be done in ascending order ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat the sorting really isn't the part that is wrong or if it is it is something I can sort out later. What I need help with is the last line of R. Where I am trying to get the dbname.servername from the row winnowed down to and place that value in the original dataset's NewServer column for the row in the current edit value.